# Unity Case sensitive file system on macOS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, filesystem, nas

I have a NAS which has all of my unity projects on it, I recently bought a MacBook Pro and have connected it to my NAS so my laptop and computer now have their own cloud sort of thing.

When I open the projects in unity on my PC, nothing happens and it happily opens them without issues. On my Mac, however, whenever I try to open them off my NAS, it just comes up with 'Fatal Error: The project is on a case sensitive file system'.

I'm guessing it's got something to do with Linux/macOS as it's only occurring on my Mac.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my way to a solution.

Open "Disk utility" application, Press "New Image" and set Format: Mac OS Extended (Journaled).
Some would suggest partitioning the harddrive.
Instead of partitioning the drive, just create a drive image that is case insensitive. (One can create an Automator workflow or AppleScript that auto opens/expands the drive image whenever Unity is launched.)
All one needs is for the Unity projects to be saved on a 'case insensitive' drive. If external is not (desired) option, then the virtual drive -- ah ha, see what I did there?, is nice alternative approach.

Answer (score 5):

Although MacOS has options to work on Case Sensitive disks, most of its applications [mainly 3rd party apps] do not work well on Case Sensitive disks, **for historical reasons**. Yet this is a future step to next versions to correctly work on Case Sensitive.

Please use any Case Insensitive disk/share to be able to not run into troubles.

Eg:
Many applications can't differentiate `thisfile.txt` from `thisFile.txt` so if you have both on any case sensitive disk, the App may get into trouble. Others may work well. It's like lottery.

MacOS [operating system] works relatively well on case sensitive disk, but 3rd party apps may not work so well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I won't be able to save my unity projects on my NAS for my Macbook to see. It works fine on my PC. I'd just like to save it on my NAS and go from my PC to my MacBook seamlessly. Is there any way around this as it only seems to happen on macOS, like what makes macOS and windows different?

Comment: @Nathan a workaround is to use version control (e.g. git) checkout to a local drive and push and pull changes between the systems.

Comment: @Mark could you explain further, please? I'm not familiar

Comment: Look at git and various tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Although MacOS has options to work on Case Sensitive disks, most of its applications [mainly 3rd party apps] do not work well on Case Sensitive disks, for historical reasons. Yet this is a future step to next versions to correctly work on Case Sensitive.

Please use any Case Insensitive disk/share to be able to not run into troubles.

Eg: Many applications can't differentiate thisfile.txt from thisFile.txt so if you have both on any case sensitive disk, the App may get into trouble. Others may work well. It's like lottery.

MacOS [operating system] works relatively well on case sensitive disk, but 3rd party apps may not work so well. (sorry I write to ask questions :D )